# Getting Users List Azure

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was using Microsoft graph API, the following issue arising in API's
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users Microsoft graph API is returning my details instead of the complete user list.

reference-:

1. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-1

Comment: Which account are you using to get the users, Personal or work account?

Comment: Hii shiva keshav, I am using my personal account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same API and was able to get entire user list. Few things to check for your scenario.

1. Make sure you have necessary permission to call List user API.

   [image]

   Refer documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to know more about List user API.

   Check access token you are using have above mentioned scope. Know scopes in access token [here](https://jwt.ms/).
2. Try calling same API from Postman/Graph Explorer and observe results.

In case you still face this issue, do share your request id and timestamp.